# Unity: OnCollisionEnter not called

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, unity

I created a sphere object, added a rigidbody component (no kinematics) and attached a script to it like this:

```
function Update () {
}

function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision) {
    Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter");
}
```

I then created a cube under the ball, added a box collider component with no trigger of course.

Then, when I run the game, the ball falls down onto the cube, but nothing happens. The `OnCollisionEnter` function isn't called.

What should I do?

Comment: Has the ball a collider attached too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I move the comment here, so we can eventually close the post.

Remember that both `GameObject` MUST have a `Collider` attached in order the `OnCollisionEnter` to be called.

As side notes:

- A `MeshCollider` cannot collide with another `MeshCollider`.
- Even if your colliders as marked as `trigger`, at least one of the 2 `GameObject` 
  involved must have a `RigidBody` attached.
- Collision between `GameObject` can be selective enabled depending on the layer the `GameObject`'s belong to. Have a look at [Layer-Based Collision Detection](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html).

Comment: well, in docs, it says, both of the objects must be rigidbody or collider. In my case, one of them is rigidbody and the other one is collider...and it doesn't works...

Comment: No, it doesn't says "or". Doc says: "When a collision between two Colliders occurs and if at least one of them has a Rigidbody attached, three collision messages are sent out to the objects attached to them." So both must have a collider and at least one of 2 a RigidBody attached.

Comment: Good bullet points to add: Each object's respective layer must be enabled for collision in the PhysicsManager, and the ability of an object to collide with another is further defined by the collision action matrix at the bottom of this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html

Comment: @michael.bartnett: good point. I've add it thanks.